# MVC ViewModel data gets clear after posting and showing validation error

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, submit

my problem it's kinda strange. So in a Index.cshtml i populate with data and in some place i use

```
@Html.Action("_Create")
```

To create a partialView where i populate with some data from the Server and with some empty fields that need to be completed for submit.

```
        [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult _Create()
    {
        var userOrder = _orderRepository.CurrentUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());
        var something = new CurrentListOrderViewModel() 
            {
                PersonName = userOrder.Select(p=>p.PersonName).FirstOrDefault(),
                Funds = userOrder.Select(p=>p.Funds).FirstOrDefault(),
                Order = "",
                OrderCosts = 0,
                Restaurant = "",
                TodayOrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                WindowsName = User.Identity.GetUserName()
            };


        return PartialView(something);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult _Create([Bind(Include = "PersonName,Funds,Order,OrderCosts,WindowsName,TodayOrderDate")]CurrentListOrderViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

So the problem is when the page loads with HTTPGET everything goes fine, the table get's populated from the database and if i change in the _Create.cshtml the @Html.EditorFor into something else so i can disable it, i lose the data. What could be the cause? I don't really understand it.

```
    @model FoodOrderQubizInterfaces.ViewModel.Order.CurrentListOrderViewModel


@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Funds, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled" }, })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Funds)
        </td>
        <td>


            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Order)
        </td>

        <td>
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Restaurant,*@

            <select>
                <option value="1">Bigys</option>
                <option value="2">Zulu</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderCosts)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderCosts)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WindowsName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WindowsName)

            <input type="submit" value="Save/Modify" class="btn btn-default" />
        </td>

        <td>


            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TodayOrderDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TodayOrderDate)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Hope you guys can help me with some advice cause i'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, after i search the web for some time. The cause was when you submit and you have the disabled attribute added it will not add to the model cause he thinks the model is disabled so the user couldn't interact with it.

So to fix it i changed from

```
<td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Funds, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled" }, })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Funds)
    </td>
```

To

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Funds, new { @readonly = true })
```

And in that was it keeps the data. I hope it will help someone else with my problem